# django-tastypie-swagger not serving Swagger's JS/CSS files

Tags: tastypie, swagger

I have a fresh install of django-tastypie and django-tastypie-swagger.

`http://localhost:8000/tasty/doc/` serves the necessary HTML, but doesn't pull in any of the CSS or JS that's needed to make it work.

`http://localhost:8000/tasty/doc/resources/` works and shows:

```
{
    basePath: "http://localhost:8000/tasty/doc/schema/",
    apis: [
        {
            path: "/snap"
        },
        {
            path: "/user"
        }
    ],
    apiVersion: "0.1",
    swaggerVersion: "1.1"
}
```

But all the others (`/schema/` and the static files) return 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you had and solved it by creating a file under my project templates directory on the following path: templates/tastypie_swagger with the content of this [file](https://github.com/concentricsky/django-tastypie-swagger/blob/master/tastypie_swagger/templates/tastypie_swagger/index.html):

Note that the problem is caused by the `STATIC_URL` variable, which is misunderstood, I replaced that variable with my project url, and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounter this problem in the future ... you might want to perform the following command after installing django-tastypie

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Simple fix add '**django.core.context_processors.static**' to '**context_processors**' in **settings.py**. Than **STATIC_URL** will work.